# Flashing and running from clion fails with OpenOCD: Error the tcl port command must be used before init

Tags: gdb, embedded, stm32, clion

Okay I have this issue for quite some time now because I never found a solution online.
I thought I will ask here and hope if someone else also encountered this issue (and with a little luck solved it).

[image]

So the expected behavior of those buttons starting with the left circled one is that the code is compiled, flashed and runs on the embedded hardware. The second circled one is the same as previous but will listen to breakpoints and start a gdb server.

When pressing the first button it will fail with the following error message:

```
[0mOpen On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0 (2020-07-29) [https://github.com/sysprogs/openocd]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
libusb1 09e75e98b4d9ea7909e8837b7a3f00dda4589dc3
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
WARNING: interface/stlink-v2.cfg is deprecated, please switch to interface/stlin
k.cfg
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override u
se 'transport select <transport>[0m'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results mi
ght differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : clock speed 2000 kHz
Info : STLINK V2J37S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.218361
Info : STM32F439VIT6.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for STM32F439VIT6.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
semihosting is enabled

Error: The 'tcl_port' command must be used before 'init'.
```

But when pressing the second button (debug), it will flash, run the code and start a gdb server all without problems.

The tooling used is:

- OpenOCD (version: OpenOCD-20200729-0.10).
- Clion (version: 2021.1 but problem persists on previous version) as my IDE.
- mingw64 installed via msys.
- arm gdb debugger (version 8.3.1)

If you have an idea what the problem could be, please let me know. I can keep using debug without breakpoints but it is annoying as hell that I just can't run.

Comment: I am also using an ST link debugger to flash the software.

Comment: Opened an issue on the Jetbrains Issue tracker. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-24752

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere down the line a fix was needed for something.

```
# Enable semihosting at startup
# Dirty fix for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7103
init
arm semihosting enable
```

Commenting the init and arm semihosting enable line fixed the problem.
Still weird it would work in debug configuration but not in run configuration. If someone knows why exactly. Please leave an answer in the comments or a post.
Happy coding :)